# Should the RegCloseKey() function only be used after a successful RegOpenKey() call, or unconditionally?

Tags: c++, windows, registry

If I call `RegOpenKeyEx()`, do I have to `RegCloseKey()` the key regardless whether `RegOpenKeyEx()` succeeded, or only if `RegOpenKeyEx()` succeeded?

That is:

```
lRes = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);

   if(lRes == ERROR_SUCCESS)
   {
       //doSomething
   }
   RegCloseKey(hKey);
```

or:

```
lRes = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);

   if(lRes == ERROR_SUCCESS)
   {
       //doSomething
       ...
       RegCloseKey(hKey);
   }
```

What is the behavior in the first case? Is closing an unsuccessfully-opened key safe?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only close it if it opened successfully, otherwise the handle returned in the HKEY will be invalid (probably NULL).

Comment: Correct. It is redundant but safe, as you will just get ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE from passing nullptr to the function.